# Как из строки удалить текст по шаблону?

Tags: php

Есть строка вида:

> Lorem Ipsum example test
>
> dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book

Из этой строки мне нужно удалить текст **Lorem Ipsum example test** . Где - **Lorem Ipsum** - всегда такой текст, а **example test** всегда разные слова. то есть получается удалить все от начала строки до первого переноса строки, при чем тега `<br>` нету, но перенос есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот этот шаблон удалит найденные совпадения в любом месте текста:

[`~Lorem Ipsum(?:\h\pL+){2}~`](https://regex101.com/r/iFiWgB/1)

---

Если нужно искать соответствия только вначале строки, добавьте *"крышку"* `^` в начало шаблона:

[`~^Lorem Ipsum(?:\h\pL+){2}~`](https://regex101.com/r/iFiWgB/2)

---

В комплекте с PHP код можно записать так:

```
$str = 'Lorem Ipsum example test

dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book';

echo preg_replace('~^Lorem Ipsum(?:\h\pL+){2}\s*~', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str=strpos($row, "\n");
$row=substr($row, 0, $str);
```

`strpos` возвращает позицию первого вхождения подстроки. Тем самым получите первый перенос строки и обрежете эту часть

upd:

```
preg_replace('/Lorem Ipsum[\w\W]*\n/', "", *текст/переменная с текстом*);
```

Comment: не совсем то что нужно. Бывают строки которые не начинаются с **Lorem Ipsum** - в таком случае там удалять ничего не нужно...

Comment: @iKey тогда нужно просто добавить `preg_match`

Comment: можете на примере показать, пожалуйста. не совсем понимаю...

Comment: @iKey немного наврал в ответе. Вырезаю строку с переносом строки. Сейчас исправлю, обновлю ответ полностью

Comment: @iKey обновил ответ